# Updating npm on windows

Tags: windows, npm

I am currently on npm version 1.2.32. When I run the following:

```
npm update npm -g
```

I get the following output:

```
npm WARN package.json cheerio-select@0.0.3 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json cli-table@0.2.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json assert-plus@0.1.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ctype@0.5.2 No repository field.
```

Then when I check version afterwards using `npm -v`, it hasn't updated. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [Fancy Windows Install](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/README.html#Fancy-Windows-Install) in the docs:

- Download zip from http://nodejs.org/dist/npm/
- Unpack in the same folder where node.exe lives